# how do i send to another from multibit bec it says "synchronizing" but it doesn't do anything WTH?

Tags: multibit

I downloaded this wallet app so im transferring coins from my multibit wallet. It says wait for the program to sync but it's taking so long.

Comment: I downvoted because of the poor questioning and overly panicky, non-researching attitude. Beside that welcome to BSE, make sure you read up on the philosophy of the SE network. Could you check if there is any bandwidth usage, or check if the files storing the blockchain are increasing in size.

Comment: yeah whatever. but thanks for the reminder though

Answer (score 0):

It could be that port 8333 is being firewalled.
There is some more about this in the MultiBit help here:
https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_network.html